# Block set by setDataTaskWillCacheResponseBlock on AFHTTPSessionManager is never called

Tags: objective-c, caching, afnetworking

I develop an application that relies heavily on AFNetworking to load data from a private API into Mantle models. My API client is a singleton subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

I'm trying to implement a basic offline mode by leveraging `NSURLCache`. The approach is to modify the request's cache policy on `dataTaskWithRequest:request:completionHandler` to `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad` if the `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` says the network is not reachable.

While I can verify that this actually works by using breakpoints during tests, the requests themselves are not being cached. I verified this by downloading the application container from Xcode, and checking the Cache.db sqlite file, which was empty. I also verified that I was looking at the correct cache by manually creating a dummy `NSCachedURLResponse` and forcefully storing it in the cache using `storeCachedResponse:forRequest`. Then the dummy response did show up in the Cache.db sqlite file.

So, I think I narrowed down the problem to my "usual" responses not being cached. I can also modify the headers sent by the server API. What I intend to do here is set a header `Cache-Control: private` on the API responses (so as not to make the other clients that use this API cache responses they shouldn't), and modify this cache header in the block of `setDataTaskWillCacheResponseBlock`, but this block never fires.

I understand that the URL system may decide when to call `URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler`, which calls the block, based on some undocumented rules, mainly the presence of a `Cache-Control` header, and the response size/cache size ratio. But my response is a 145-byte JSON, and the `Cache-Control` header is set (I verified both via `curl -v` and inspecting the `task` parameter of the `success` block of my request.

I also tried a more aggressive cache header, `Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000`, to see if this caches the response or at least calls the block, but the behaviour was exactly the same. I also checked the `myAFHTTPSessionManagerSubclass.session.delegate` property, which was indeed pointing to `myAFHTTPSessionManagerSubclass`, as expected.

I also tried overriding `URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler` directly in my subclass, but it still was not called. Setting a breakpoint on this same delegate method on `AFURLSessionManager.m` in the `Pods` directory also does not work, the execution never stops on the breakpoint.

I'm using version 2.5.4 of AFNetworking, according to my `Podfile.lock` file.

**So, how to make my responses cache (preferably without setting agressive caching policies on the response), so I can implement a quick offline mode in my app?**

*EDIT*: I also tried to create a `NSURLSession` to see if this would work. So, I created a simple Node.js server that just answers something simple and sets a cache header:

```
$ curl -v http://192.168.1.107:1337/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.1.107...
* Connected to 192.168.1.107 (192.168.1.107) port 1337 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: 192.168.1.107:1337
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Cache-Control: public
< Date: Thu, 11 Jun 2015 14:38:14 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
Hello World
```

And then created a simple view controller to test:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Prime the cache
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:[[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:2*1024 diskCapacity:10*1024*1024 diskPath:@"mytestcache"]];
    // The sleep is to be absolutely sure the cache did initialise
    sleep(2);

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.107:1337"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Got response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    }] resume];
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)proposedResponse completionHandler:(void (^)(NSCachedURLResponse *))completionHandler {

    completionHandler(proposedResponse);
}
```

The response is correctly printed, but `willCacheResponse` is never called (I set a breakpoint). I tried checking the container again, and the `mytestcache` directory was created, but it was empty. I also tried `Cache-Control: max-age=86400`, to the same result.

*( cross-posted to AFNetworking issues at: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2780 )*

Answer (score 2):

Well, I will surprise you - the code you wrote above is working just fine, ...but it's incorrect for what you're trying to achieve ;)

Reason is simply - delegate methods are not being called when you create requests by method `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:`. You need to use method `dataTaskWithRequest:` instead.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1 - read first **Note**

Second thing is that NSURLSession just really sux when we talk about caching. You may face several issues in iOS 7.x/8.x. I faced such nightmare when I was implementing custom cache in my app, which eventually has nothing in common with NSURLCache. Also I decided to create my kind of framework based on NSURLSession and AFNetworking.

One of the issues on iOS 7 is creating `NSURLSession` with `defaultConfiguration`, the `NSURLCache` object will be different than global one - quite unexpected behaviour.
One of the issues on iOS 8 is that the POST requests are also being cached, which may compromise security of your app. BTW https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=nsurlcache+ios+8+broken

Maybe it does not answer your questions, but you should be aware of that strange behaviours and differences between iOS versions.
Honestly I recommend you to use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager instead of AFHTTPSessionManager, because at least NSURLConnection works like a harm with NSURLCache :)